# How to render non-overlaping object?

Tags: c++, opengl, rendering, transformation

I implement manipulators as in CAD systems. My manipulator is a separate model. I do not know how to implement so that the manipulator does not overlap with other objects during rendering. To keep the manipulator in the foreground

Example:

[image]

I can't seem to find any functions in OpenGL that can do this.

Comment: What do you mean by `does not overlap`? How does it currently look like?

Comment: Whenever you add a tag you should read the description. `depth` has the description `The depth of a node in a tree is the length of the path to its root.` so how should that be related to your question?

Comment: Draw the manipulator last with depth-testing and optionally depth-buffer updating off.  Drawing an object last with depth-testing off will give the appearance of being in-front (or on top) of all other obejcts.